# Mouse event handlers on SVG elements - preventing propagation?

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-events

I have an `<svg>` element which has multiple child `<g>` elements which have jQuery mouse event handlers bound to them. So when a `mousedown` event fires on one of these elements it is highlighted, like this:

```
('.foo').bind('mousedown', function(e) {
     ($(this).find("*")).each(function(child) {
        child.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
        child.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
     });
});
```

I want the element to be *un*highlighted when the user clicks on another part of the SVG. My previous implementation involved HTML5 canvas, so all the event handlers were bound to the same non-hierarchical object. I am struggling to understand how to reimplement this using SVG, however. I thought it would be enough to bind a handler for `mousedown` to the root SVG element itself, but this seems to override the `<g>` element handler completely.

I guess I have to somehow prevent event propagation up the hierarchy. I've come across references to this kind of thing - is that the right solution, and how might I implement it?

**Update:** Adding `e.stopPropagation()` *seems* to work; but is that the best solution? Seems almost like a hack.

Comment: Why would `stopPropagation()` seem "like a hack"? Stopping propagation is literally exactly what the title of your question is asking how to do.

Comment: @sphanley Yes, I _should_ have phrased the title differently. But I was somewhat influenced by [this](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) article. In fact I've implemented the solution on that page also. I'm not yet sure what the best choice is.

Answer (score 0):

[The OP wrote in an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que):

Adding `e.stopPropagation()` *seems* to work; but is that the best solution? Seems almost like a hack.

@samHanley wrote:

Why would `stopPropagation()` seem "like a hack"? Stopping propagation is literally exactly what the title of your question is asking how to do.

[The OP wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat):

Yes, I should have phrased the title differently. But I was somewhat influenced by [this](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) article. In fact I've implemented the solution on that page also. I'm not yet sure what the best choice is